# What is the Google Maps interactive map written in?

Tags: java, flash, html, applet

I just had an idea for a cool website, but it would require an application that is fairly similar to the Google Maps interactive map. I was wondering what it was made in?

Is it a Java applet or a Flash application? Or something else?

Thanks a lot

Comment: The 'street view' is implemented in Flash (with a beta version in WebGL, where supported).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Maps#Implementation). Lots and lots of javascript, with [JSON](http://json.org/example.html) for loading new data without refreshing the entire page.

If you'd like to know more, there's quite a community revolving around [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) that specialize in extending/reverse engineering the google maps codebase.

Comment: Woah, that is impressive, and very much out of my scope! In addition my idea needs the users input to be saved to a server, which I believe JavaScript couldn't do?

Comment: I believe you could support an entire web application, front to back, using Javascript and `[YOUR DATABASE HERE]`. Granted, there are languages that can do more than javascript in some areas, but overall, it is a very well rounded language.

Answer (score 1):

Another option for your mapping app: Program it it Java building off NASA's free WorldWind geospatial API.  You could release it either as a standalone app, or as a JApplet that runs within browsers.  The latter simplifies distribution and versioning.

Answer (score 0):

Google API is Javascript. It is also available in Flash.
Bing map is using the same sytem and it is available in javascript or silverlight.
You may also be interested in openstreetmap (free alternative).

If you want to build a tile system from the ground, the easier is to use flash. You will avoid cross browser issues, and easely target large audiance. (I made one long time ago before gmap was out).

If your application require a map, you can use either Map API and build your application on top of it. Be aware that some kind of application and some uses require a licence fee and the entry ticket is quite high ($10k for gmap).

Answer (score 0):

For the client side they are using the [Google Closure Library](https://developers.google.com/closure/library/), with a lot of extra javascript on top.

Answer (score 0):

Rolling Thunder has had the flyby capability for many years. You load a gpx file then you can fly over or just slightly above group and can control the rate you fly and can pause and look around. It works on windows or the Mac OSX. You can find the Windows version at http://www.myuniportal.com/download.html Download the Map login version and then open a Map child window the select the foot button on the Map child window. You download a gpx file then press play and it will start at one end of the trail and fly over it.